# Как нарисовать ось Х и ось Y?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, графика, matplotlib

Как в *python*, в библиотеке `matplotlib`, нарисовать оси `Х` и `Y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(40))

x = np.arange(-20, 20)

plt.plot(x, y)

ax = plt.gca()

# plot X - axis    
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')

# plot Y - axis    
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или же можно передвинуть стандартные оси в центр:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо :3 заработало, а есть ли документация как начать работать с этой библиотекой пошагово, а то я как то не справился (не нашёл ), только стандартная документация а она не всегда говорит откуда начать

Comment: Попробуйте начать с [Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html)